# Form handling in Yii2 (ActiveForm): Dropdown list visibility depending on radio Button selection

Tags: yii2

I am creating an ActiveForm in Yii2. Among other fields, I use a radioList having the values "YES"/"NO". 
What I want to do is: display or not a dropDownList, depending on the selection of the former radioList (only if "NO" is selected, the dropDownList should be visible).

I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

PS: I provide the sample code just for referencing

```
.....
<?= Html::radioList('rd_id', $defaultVal, ['1'=>' YES ','0'=>' NO '], ['separator'=>' ']); ?>
.....
<?= Html::label('label: ','select'); ?>
<?= Html::dropDownList('select', '', $listdata, ['class'=>'xxxxxxx']); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Register this js :

```
$this->registerJs('
    $(".xxxxxxx").show();
    $("[name=rd_id]").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 0) {
            $(".xxxxxxx").hide();
        } else {
            $(".xxxxxxx").show();
        }
    });
');
```